Can I use puppeteer to get fully interactable webpage?
So I have a NextJS route that I want to essentially copy the page's contents, assets, and js into (ideally) a single file. I'm using puppeteer to go to the route and I can download it as an mhtml. However, while all the visually assets and styles are there, my onClicks don't work. Am I missing something that would get me a fully hydrated version? Or is my general approach wrong?
Just to be clear, here's how I'm generating the mhtml:
const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
const page = await browser.newPage();

await page.goto(
    `http://localhost:3000/myRoute`,
    {
      waitUntil: "networkidle0",
    },
);

await page.setViewport({ width: 1080, height: 1024 });

const session = await page.createCDPSession();

await session.send("Page.enable");


const { data } = await session.send("Page.captureSnapshot");


If your goal is to download a whole webpage with JS, why not use a tool specifically designed for that, like this?

@ggorlen I read through the docs earlier, its section on dynamic content made it seem like it wouldn't support onClicks. Or am I mistaken? Here's a quote:
"Monolith doesn't feature a JavaScript engine, hence websites that retrieve and display data after initial load may require usage of additional tools."

I picked that at random, so it may not be the right one, but the same suggestion applies. I figured once it downloads the site, and you open it in a browser, then you have a JS engine. The key is getting the relevant JS scripts downloaded into your bundle. Maybe Puppeteer can do it, it just seems like an unusual way to go about it--surely there are plenty of "download entire website with JS" tools. I may be mistaken.
